# Unit test through an oauth flow in Django

Tags: django, unit-testing, oauth

I have an oauth flow in which a user grants access to a certain scope and then my application can do stuff.  For this to work, I need an access token with the defined scope.
I implemented this (with the django allauth package) and it works great.  But...
I would like to **test** it.
This is what I have so far (request package is like an urllib on steroids):

```
    login = self.client.login(username='test_user', password='test')
    self.assertTrue(login)

    resp = self.client.post(reverse('oauth_login'))
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)

    payload = {'session_key': 'email', 'session_password': 'pw', }

    resp2 = requests.post(resp['location'], data=payload)

    resp3 = self.client.get(reverse('do_stuff_with_access_token'))
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 302)
```

The issue here is that I do not get the access token in my request variables.  My guess is that I am going out of the scope of the application and Django does not get the variable in its request scope.

How can you test this in an elegant manner?  Mocking an access_token seems a bit wrong to me.  I am now trying to go Selenium for filling in the form, but even that is not really a success so far...

Thanks!

Comment: What OAuth library are you using?

Comment: Why does mocking seem wrong? You aren't testing the remote service, you are testing how your application handles responses and failures from the remote service. That sounds like a perfect use case for mocking.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I am using django allauth.  Don't know how exactly it implements oauth, guess it is dependent on the service you are calling.

Comment: @MarkLavin I was assuming that there is a time limit on tokens?  You actually make me think that this assumption could be wrong though...  let me try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kudos to Mark!

To help anyone on their way.
Mocking worked out.  In my case (django 1.4) you need to add your tokens to the session.  A lot of different advices can be found on the net, but I like simple things and this works in Django at least with the test suite:

```
session = self.client.session
session['request_token'] = {...}
session['access_token'] = {...}
session.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem and found the following solved my dilemma:

```
user = User.objects.get(username='lauren')
client = APIClient()
client.force_authenticate(user=user)
```

This was taken directly from the Django documentation:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#force_authenticateusernone-tokennone

Unfortunately it took a number of searches before getting to this point. I hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: Looks like an elegant approach to it, nice! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: for people still finding this answer while searching, note that this does *not* associate the user with a `request.session`, and so while the user object has been marked as authenticated, as far as get/post operations through the APIClient go this user still does not exist - it's only a local variable, not a true session-associated user.